# Unboundedness in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

Let $K = \{ x :  Ax \le b, x \ge 0 \}$, $b \ge 0$. If there are solutions $x \ge 0$ different from zero of $A x \le 0$, show that $K$ is unbounded.(A is mxn, x is 1xn b is 1xm matrix.)

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_0 \ge 0$ be a non-zero solution of $Ax \le 0$. Then, for each $t \ge 0$, we have $tx_0 \ge 0$ and
$$ A(tx_0) = tAx_0 \le 0 \le b $$
hence $tx_0 \in K$. As
$$ \| tx_0 \| = t\|x_0\| \to \infty, \quad t \to \infty $$
$K$ is unbounded.